# Removing invalid characters from price

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a scenario where I have to remove certain characters from a price string using C#.

I'm looking for a regular expression to remove these characters or something better than that.

For example, if the price string is

```
"3,950,000 ( Ex. TAX )"
```

I want to remove `"( Ex. TAX )"` from the string.

Basically I have to remove the any character from string except numbers, dot and comma.

Comment: actully its only examplae...there must be some other char..

Comment: But you have a dot in "Ex. TAX" do you want to keep or remove that?

Comment: It would come the similar way like you have shown with bracket or do you think it can come other way?

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are always tricky to get right, since the input can vary so greatly, but I *think* this one covers your needs:

```
string pattern = @"([\d]+[,.]{0,1})+";
string cleanedPrice = Regex.Match(price, pattern).Value;
```

Explained:

```
(         - start matching group
[\d]+     - match any decimal digit, at least once
[,.]{0,1} - ...followed by 0 or 1 comma or dot
)         - end of group
+         - repeat at least once
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a RegEx when a simple replace will do?

```
string clean = "3,950,000 ( Ex. TAX )".Replace(" ( Ex. TAX )", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
myPrice.Replace(" ( Ex. TAX ),"")
```

Comment: my scenario is that. i have to remove the any character from string except number,dot(.), and comma(,)

Answer (score 1):

```
String price = "3,950,000 ( Ex. TAX)".Replace(" ( Ex. TAX)","");
```

Comment: my scenario is that. i have to remove the any character from string except number,dot(.), and comma(,)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regular expression

Case 1: if ( Ex.TAX ) is constant, you can just remove the text using string function String.Replace.

Case 2: if you require number which contains only , following is the regex you can use to extract the same

> [0-9,]{1,}

Case 3: if ( is there always there after number, the following regex can be used

> \d.*(?=\()

following is c# code for regex

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      "\\d.*(?=\\() ",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
//// Capture the first Match, if any, in the InputText
// Match m = regex.Match(InputText);
```

Comment: my scenario is that. i have to remove the any character from string except number,dot(.), and comma(,)

Comment: Hi Shivi, I think 2nd case will work for you. But you need to be sure that only 1 number is there in your string. for more than two number it wont return proper result. You can use [0-9,.]{1,} but again there is issue. As there is . in between text. So you need to first make sure that there is only 1 number and it is in first location. Can you write some sample examples so that it would be easy to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

To find "( Ex. TAX )" try this regex:

```
/\( Ex\. TAX \)/i
```

Comment: my scenario is that. i have to remove the any character from string except number,dot(.), and comma(,)

Comment: @Shivi, please just edit the question if things need clarification, rather than repeating the same comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Regex rex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:\d{1,2},)?(?:\d{3},)*(?:\d{3})(?:\.\d+){0,})|(\d+)");

 Console.WriteLine(rex.Match("3,950,000 ( Ex. TAX )").Groups[0].Captures[0].Value);
 Console.WriteLine(rex.Match("3,950,000,000").Groups[0].Captures[0].Value);
 Console.WriteLine(rex.Match("3,950,000,000UHFWF#FWHFWEFE").Groups[0].Captures[0].Value);
 Console.WriteLine(rex.Match("3,950,000,000,000,000.00").Groups[0].Captures[0].Value);
```

Output:

- 3,950,000
- 3,950,000,000
- 3,950,000,000
- 3,950,000,000,000,000.00